# Cron jobs do not run in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cron, node-cron

I am developing a Nodejs server which I am uploading to Heroku. The file has a Cron job which is meant to run every 4th hour. But when I check in nothing happens. I am using the free version of Heroku and I do not appear to be exceeding my limit of free Dyno hours.

The code in my Index.js file looks like below. As you can see in this simple example, I just want the application to log the time every 4th hour. I also update a variable which should indicate the latest update, which can be used to check for status of updates.

```js
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import cors from 'cors';
app.use(cors());
import cron from 'node-cron';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3050;

var lasttime = '';
var task = cron.schedule("0 0 */4 * * *",() => {
        console.log("date: "+Date());
        lasttime = Date();
    }, {
        scheduled: true
    }
 );

app.get('/api_x', async (request, response) => {
reply=lasttime;
response.json({reply:reply});
});
```

This works fine when I run it on my local computer. When I run it on Heroku it logs the message once, doesn't update the variable lasttime and then does nothing.
When I check the logs for the App on Heroku it reads:

`Unidling`
`State changed from down to starting`
`Starting process with command npm start`
`webdesign@1.0.0 start /app`
`node index.js`
`listening at 10006`
`State changed from starting to up`

What could be causing my Cron job not to run?
(I have also tried using setInterval, but still no results.)

Answer (score 2):

In the free version of Heroku the server sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity, otherwise always on depending on your remaining monthly free dyno hours.

The Hobby plan Never sleeps

[Heroku Pricing](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)